# Kafka DSL - Manual Commit with Message

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We are trying to implement manual commit with Spring DSL Kafka with the below code. We couldn't find any reference to it.

We can add consumer porperty as "Auto.commit" as "False", but we wanted to commit the message once we process the message successfully. Can some one help on this?

```
@Bean
        IntegrationFlow consumer()  {
    KafkaHighLevelConsumerMessageSourceSpec messageSourceSpec = Kafka
                    .inboundChannelAdapter(new ZookeeperConnect(this.kafkaConfig.getZookeeperAddress()))
                    .consumerProperties(
                            props -> props.put("zookeeper.session.timeout.ms", "500").put("zookeeper.sync.time.ms", "250").
                            put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer").
                            put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer").
                            put("auto.offset.reset", "smallest").
                            put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "100")
                            )
                    .addConsumer(this.kafkaConfig.getConsumerGroup(),
                            metadata -> metadata.consumerTimeout(100)
                                    .topicStreamMap(m -> m.put(this.kafkaConfig.getTopicRead(), 1)).maxMessages(1));

            Consumer<SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec> endpointConfigurer = e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(100));
            return IntegrationFlows.from(messageSourceSpec, endpointConfigurer)
                    .<Map<String, List<byte[]>>> handle((payload, headers) -> {
                        payload.entrySet().forEach(e -> processMessage((ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, List<byte[]>>) e.getValue()));
                        return null;
                    }).get();
        }
```

Version:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-java-dsl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: There is an Acknowledge object in the headers that allows you to commit.

Answer (score 0):

See related GH issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/69.

The solution sounds like:

Looking to this closely I'd say that you have to commit offsets manually:

```
ConsumerConnector
...
/**
   *  Commit the offsets of all broker partitions connected by this connector.
   */
  public void commitOffsets();
  public void commitOffsets(boolean retryOnFailure);
```

That is a Kafka `Consumer` bridge on which the `KafkaHighLevelConsumerMessageSource` is based.

You can get access to that via `KafkaConsumerContext` bean. Unfortunately it is registered with some generated name like, `org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.KafkaConsumerContext#0` , but if you have only one such a Kafka Consumer (`KafkaHighLevelConsumerMessageSourceSpec messageSourceSpec`), you can just get that bean by type (or just `@Autowired` it).

After that you can go like:

```
kafkaConsumerContext.getConsumerConfiguration(this.kafkaConfig.getConsumerGroup())
                                    .getConsumerConnector()
                                    .commitOffsets();
```